# Append / Insert Into DOM Fails for Element Node

Tags: javascript, html

I setup the following `console.log`'s to make sure of what my variable contains.

```
console.log(globalAttributes[0])
console.log(globalAttributes[0].outerHTML)
```

These return:

```
HTMLElement {}
<code id="global-attributes:the-accesskey-attribute"><a href="interaction.html#the-accesskey-attribute">accesskey</a></code>
```

And when I try either `.append` or `.appendChild` nothing shows up on my resulting HTML page. And if I try inserting as `.innerHTML` the text shows up as expected unrendered.

I'm using JSDOM in Node.js and

```
fs.writeFileSync("elements.html", prettify.prettyPrint(doc.body.innerHTML), {indent_size: 2});
```

Everything else is working fine. Any ideas why `.append` and `.appendChild` fail to inject the Element node?

```
            attributesSummaryElement.textContent = "Attributes";
            attributesDetailsElement.appendChild(attributesSummaryElement);
            console.log(globalAttributes[0])
            console.log(globalAttributes[0].outerHTML)
            attributesDetailsElement.appendChild(globalAttributes[0])
```

Comment: You're in a `<details>` element right? That's what it does: hide everything after the `<summary>` until you open it. You can add the `open` attribute on the `<details>` element if you want it to be open by default.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the reply, but I don't think that's what is going on. I append the `summary` element first, then I want to append other stuff too. It should display. Like for example https://codepen.io/ronnieroyston/pen/ZEjZXRe

Comment: But in that codepen you did set the `open` attribute.

Comment: It's open in my result page too. Manually. I open it. I was just doing a sanity check with that codepen to show that you can add element nodes to the details element

Comment: Show a live example or at least enough to reproduce the issue.